# Restricting method calls to 1 per sec with Java?

Tags: java, aspectj

I am writing a program, and I would only like the user to be able to make certain method calls every 1 second. I'm having trouble figuring out the best way to do this in Java.

The best idea I can come up with is having a pointcut for the method calls I want to restrict and having some sort of static variable (stored where?) of when the last call was, and sleeping as necessary. Is this good practice?

Thanks!

Edit: the method calls are hitting a busy webserver, and thus they should be restricted to 1 per second.

Edit2: I am writing a client to access a server. I do not have any control over the server.

Comment: Wait, wat? What makes you think this is a good idea?

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I mis-stated the problem. It isn't exactly an API. The method calls will be making requests to a busy server, which has the restriction that only one request can be made every 1 second. See the EDIT.

Comment: Well, for what it's worth, the "busy webserver" is poorly designed if they expect the *consumer* to do the throttling.

Comment: Do you have control on both the client and the server? Is the client a Java client? Is the server a Java server?

Comment: A lot of online APIs (Last FM, EchoNest, Reddit, Digg) prefer to only be queried roughly once per second. This is a similar situation. In regard to the other comments, see the second edit.

Comment: What do you want to happen if your client tries to make calls to rapidly? You want it to wait? Throw an exception? What if it tries to make rapid calls for a long time?

Comment: @erickson, the client should sleep until it is able to make another call.

Answer (score 4):

This is pretty common for scenarios like "refresh", etc. where there it is desirable to limit the frequency.

I would use a separate worker thread. The method invocation signals the thread and returns immediately. The tread wakes up, checks how long it has been since the last execution and runs if necessary. The long field tracking last execution can be a member variable of the thread.

Comment: It is indeed very common, it is one kind of event filtering.  Such a technique is very common in video games, for example (there was an excellent article on Gamasutra back in the days as to how event filtering has been applied to the *Age of Empire* series to gain huge perfs boost).  Basically you intercept events (say all the "mouse drag" events) and only re-cast them as allowed/needed by your program (for example only re-casting 10 "mouse drag" events even if the mouse was dragged continuously for 30 seconds).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I suppose my question is more geared towards how to structure the code which will restrict the methods, ie creating a pointcut for specific method calls. Do you think this is a good approach?

Comment: Ok. I see that you are asking an AOP specific question. Cannot answer that, I am afraid. Not an AOP user.

Answer (score 2):

Why would you do this?  If I had to give some kind of solution to something this quirky, I'd say you use

```
System.currentTimeMillis()
```

to keep track of the last time the method was called, and simply return if one second has not passed from now till the last time the method was called.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it by using a queue of commands and then a fixed rate scheduler to dispatch those commands at the required rate.  You could even build in some logic to detect if new commands entering the queue could be coalesced with existing un-dispatched commands.  Take a look at [java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutor](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/j2se/j2se/1.5.0/jcp/beta1/apidiffs/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutor.html) and the [command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern)

Answer (score 0):

I assume the user has to press a button to call this method. I would disable the button until the user is allowed to click it again.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you would want to this. Are you trying conserve memory, or CPU? Assuming you have a web app with multiple threads you could use something like a java.util.concurrent.Semaphore which is a counting semaphore to to limit the number of threads that can execute that code to the number in the Semaphore http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html

You could also use some of the thread pooling schedulers that are part of java.util.concurrent to create a certain number of threads in a thread pool and then assign work to them that way you can limit how often a particular piece of code executes.

There are other data structures in java.util.concurrent that could be useful such as BlockingQueue

If you tell us more about the context of your application we can help you better.